# Is your career ratio relevant for matchmaking?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Is my personal career rating relevant for the matchmaking?

If I have a low score, do I get placed into a game with other players with low scores (and same for high score), or are people matched together regardless of their personal score?

Edit:
After some research i found some speculation threads where some people think there is indeed a career based matchmaking because of longer waiting times for high career points players. But this only pure speculation without facts, it would be nice if somebody knows a reliable statement of developers or fact based information.

Answer (score -1):

yes somewhat, sadly the system for matchmaking is broken, which also depends on your server, in Asia they match with silvers I believe and the USA gets platinum. your kd plays a giant part also.

Comment: Can you provide some more details and possibly some references? This reads more as a comment rather than a true answer.